# Running other programs in Tcl

Tags: tcl, exec

I have to run a program written in a proprietary non Tcl language inside a Tcl program and collect its output for further processing by the rest of my Tcl program.

I tried using exec command but it errored out with: Couldn't execute ..... no such file or directory message.

This is how I am running it:

```
set x [exec readDataBaseVals data]
```

as I have to use the value of $x for further processing. This gives the following error

```
couldn't execute "readDataBaseVals": no such file or directory
```

Comment: We need the _exact_ error message. The bit with the …… is the critical bit for helping us help you.

Comment: Here is how I am running it: % set x [exec readDataBaseVals data] 
couldn't execute "readDataBaseVals": no such file or directory

Comment: Here is how I am running it:</br>

Comment: Are you sure that the file `readDataBaseVals` available in the current directory or at least present in `path` variable ?